# Configure multiple onesignal notification in single domain

Tags: php, laravel, subdirectory, onesignal

I want to implement multiple onesignal notification in single domain.

**Need**

Like there's a domain **domain.com** now i want different notification for **domain.com/en**, **domain.com/esp** and so on

**Tried**

I've configured different web push notification for different sub directory whose **app id** is supposed to be:

```
app_id_en //for domain.com/en
app_id_esp //for domain.com/esp
```

Also, I've enabled advance option in which Path to service worker files give **/en** and **/esp**

Below code i've used for each particular language
[image]

Advance settings
[image]

As per onesignal documentation I've served both workers file **OneSignalSDKWorker.js** and **OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js** within subdirectory.

That means, OneSignalSDKWorker.js is accessible at

**domain.com/en/OneSignalSDKWorker.js**

**domain.com/en/OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js**

**Result**
NOT WORKING :(

Answer (score 0):

**FYI** there are some configuration you need to do while creating oneSignal app

I would suggest you to go with **Typical Settings** for batter app configuration

- Look at the urls you've added in Onesignal App, that should be same. (If trying on local system then you can create a app and give local url)
- As per the service workers you web site should be https, if not then you need to turn off the https support from the OneSignal app.
- As code says you need not to set the bell icon  by code (it's optional) but you can set these from you OneSignal app configuration
- In console you can see the error for respective reasons of not working
- OneSignal add an key in localStorage for debug, so you can set it to true for more logs

*go with Typical Settings that's really lifesaver* [DOCUMENTATION](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-quickstart)

Comment: I'm already using typical settings. Also, I've edited my question you can see my advance option custom  settings screenshot @RonakBokaria

Comment: Everything looks good here, please enable debugging as I said on answer and take screenshot of console errors so I can tell you what exactly going wrong there

Comment: Now i'm facing another issue, On clicking allow, user is not subscribing also no error is showing in console. @RonakB

Comment: That's great!! Go to OneSignal and check the audience list your will find your answer there.